# Replace multi minus to one minus by regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace

There is a string

```
str = "test--removing-----minus-";
```

Trying to replace by

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\-*", @"-");
```

but I get

```
"t-e-s-t--r-e-m-o-v-i-n-g--m-i-n-u-s-";
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you get a letter `b` added to your output

Comment: Copy-paste error. Thanks. Fixed! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` matches **0 or more** match of previous pattern. Use `{2,}` to match `2 or more` match.

And `-` is not needed to be escaped.

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"-{2,}", @"-");
```

Comment: My first thought was that it would be more concise to just say "one or more" but then I realised that might make the regex into `"-+"`... Also the `@` are not needed before the strings too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `*` matches *zero* or more characters, meaning that it matches between letters.

Change it to `+` which means *one* or more.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be,

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\-+", @"-");
```

OR

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\-{1,}", @"-");
```

`*` makes the regex greedy and it represents zero or more times. SO it put `-` on zero occurrences. Use `{1,}` to match one or more occurrences of the character `-`